# Clear a linked table location, but keep the link

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database that works as a user interface to a few other databases. I link the secondary databases into the "front end" with linked tables.

So I have A.accdb, B.accdb, C.accdb, which all link into UI.accdb.

When I give this to people, some only get A, some only get B, some get A and C, and so on. The databases are expected to all be in the same folder. I am able to update the links by having a macro that relinks the UI back to each using the following (with some error handling).

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strConnect As String, dbName As String
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

strConnect = ";DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\"

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
        tdf.Connect = sMyConnectString & dbName
        tdf.RefreshLink
    End If
Next tdf
```

My problem is that if a user does not get B, for example, then their table links will not update location and the old file location is still saved in the link (but will not work since they don't have the file). I want to clean this up though.

Is there a way that in the error handling I can set `tdf.connect` to something that doesn't exist? I cannot set it to `Null` and I cannot seem to set it to some arbitrary string. Are there any other options to make the link not work, not show the previous location, but still exist? I want it to remain in case they get one of the other databases later.

Comment: The simple method would be supply all backends in any case, just having one or more of these tables with no records.

Comment: You could just delete the link altogether. Is there a reason you are keeping it around for a user that doesn't have the file to use it?

Comment: Another option would be to send them all files and simply don't provide any data rows on the files you didn't want them to have.

Comment: I think providing zero-row databases might be the cleanest. I wanted the link because I might provide one of the backends later on, and that would make things simple. But I guess I would just provide a new front end in that case. Useful discussion. Thank you